# About prediction on higher populations

Tags: confidence-interval

Usually, when we do prediction algorithms we are happy obtaining a specific classification rate on a population. My question is: Is there any way of extending that result to wider populations? In other words, if I obtain a 89% of successful classification rate on 1000 individuals, what can I say about the performance of my classifier on a population of 1Million individuals? I assume that the percentage may vary (probably descending) but I wonder if there is any confidence interval or so that can be applied here.

Thank you.

Comment: The sample of 1000 needs to be representative of the 1000000 (or however many) population you want to generalise to.  For example, if the sample was 100% males aged 30-50 and the population was all people your results may generalise poorly.

Comment: The need to obtain a test set using some form of randomization is basic, but pointing that out does not answer the question. It can be answered provided the classifier's results are tabulated. That is, for each pair $(i,j)$ of the possible categories you need to record the number of individuals in the test set who were in category $i$ and classified into category $j$. This gives sufficient information to estimate (and provide confidence limits for) the proportions of each category in the parent population as well as the likely range (and types) of misclassifications that would occur.

Answer (score 3):

If the sample of 1000 is a random sample of the larger population *and* you developed the algorithm on a training set and then used a test set of the sample of 1000 to get the confidence interval and you didn't do anything else against the "rules" then the confidence interval ought to be the same in the wider population as it is in the test set of the sample.

Perhaps different groups use words differently, but usually the word "population" in the second line of your question would be "sample", and usually the prediction rate on the wider population is what we are really interested in. After all, with the sample, we *know* what the right results are.

Comment: And what happens if your population (not sample) increases a lot? Will the generalization capability of your algorithm decrease?
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the size of the population to which you can infer is constant: It is the population as it was when you  took the random sample. It can't increase or decrease. In practice, inferences to some other population  are often made, but these will not be mathematically correct. How the estimates will change is not calculable - it depends on how the population differs from the sample.

Comment: I see your point and I agree completely.

Comment: What confidence interval are you refering to?